# Filter data from two arrays in a third array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to take a complement of two arrays and populate a third array with the remaining data. I have a `this.subjects` object and a `this.teacerData` proprties from which i have taken out subjects code and put them in two different arrays. Now i am trying to filter out the data that is not equal in both arrays and put it into a third array.

```
subj: Subjects[];
teacherSubjects: string[];
data: string[];
filteredData: string[];
addsubject: AddTeacherSubject = new AddTeacherSubject();
teacherData: TeacherUpdateDataDto = new TeacherUpdateDataDto();

ngOnInit() {
this._curriculumService.getSubject(this.appSession.tenant.tenancyName)
.finally(() => { this.saving = false;})
.subscribe((result: listResultDtoOfSubjectDto) => {
  this.subjects = result.items;
  this.teacherSubjects = this.subjects.map(a => a.code);
  console.log("All Subjects =" + this.teacherSubjects);
 })

this._teacherService.GetTeacherUpdateData(this.appSession.tenant.tenancyName, 
this._sharedService.getMessage())
.finally(()=> { this.saving = false;})
.subscribe((result: TeacherUpdateDataDto) => {
  this.teacherData = result;
  this.subj = this.teacherData.subject;
  this.data = this.subj.map(a => a.code);
})
}
```

this.subjects DTO

```
(3) [subjectlistDto, subjectlistDto, subjectlistDto]
0 :
 subjectlistDto {name: "Mathematics", code: "mathematics", classCode: "bscs", 
 classNAME: "BSCS"}
1 :
 subjectlistDto {name: "English", code: "english", classCode: "bscs", 
 classNAME: "BSCS"}
2 :
 subjectlistDto {name: "Islamiat", code: "islamiat", classCode: "bscs", 
 classNAME: "BSCS"}
```

this.teacherData Dto

```
subject:Array(2)
0:
{code: "mathematics"}
1:
{code: "english"}
```

I need the filtered data in filteredSubjects array. How can i do that?

Comment: post this.subjects and this.teacerData

Comment: okay i am editing then

Comment: `this.data` and `this.teacherSubjects` have been initialized with only codes so now i want to apply filter on these two arrays

Comment: Does the `this.teacherData` have objects with only one property - `code`?

Comment: yes it has a subject array in which there is only one property code

Comment: what do you want as ouput

Comment: difference of `this.data` and `this.teacherSubjects`

Comment: in this case you need  {
    "name": "Islamiat",
    "code": "islamiat",
    "classCode": "bscs",
    "classNAME": "BSCS"
  } ?

Comment: nope i only need code as output

Comment: so only Ismaiat ?

Comment: yes i only need islamiat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which version of rxjs you are using but look into `forkJoin` or `combineLatest`. These allow you to combine the results of multiple observables into one request.
[Combine latest example](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) and [Fork join](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). Once you have both sets of data emitted comparing items to filter into a third is simple.

Edit: If you want to filter the arrays for only the items that appear once then do something like this then:

```
function getDistinctValues(array1, array2): [] {
    const finalArray = [...array1, ...array2];

    finalArray = finalArray.sort((item1, item2) => {
         return item1 === item2 ? 0 : item1 > item2 ? 1 : -1;
    });

    let pointer = finalArray.length-1;

    while(pointer > 0) {
        if(finalArray[pointer] === finalArray[pointer-1]) {
            finalArray.splice(pointer-1, 2);
            pointer--;
        }
        pointer--;
    }
    return finalArray;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me if i can make use of filter and how?

Comment: edited it to include an example on how to get just the items that dont appear in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it

Just called Data function fron ngOnInit and

```
Data(subjec: string[], compar: string[]) {
this.filteredData = [];
for(var i = 0; i< subjec.length; i++) {
  if(compar.indexOf(subjec[i]) === -1){
    this.filteredData.push(subjec[i]);
  }
}
for(var j = 0; j<compar.length; j++) {
  if(subjec.indexOf(compar[j]) === -1){
    this.filteredData.push(compar[j]);
  }
}
return this.filteredData;

}
```